# Algorithm for minimum sum subvector

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-pearls

The problem found in programming pearls column 8 is as follows:

**Given the real vector x[n], compute the maximum sum found in any contiguous subvector.**

The final solution provided is of O(n) complexity which is as follows:

```
std::vector<int> x;
int max_so_far = 0;
int max_here = 0;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
{
   max_here = std::max(max_here + x[i], 0);
   max_so_far = std::max(max_so_far, max_here);
}
```

I would like to know how does one go about modifing the above algorithm to provide the *minimum sum*.

Comment: Set x[n] = -x[n] and run the max sum...

Comment: You could multiply all vector elements by -1, run the vector through the code above, and again multiply the sum found by -1.

Comment: @Reyzooti - I have a doubt. Does the term "subvector" include only the vectors starting from position 0?

Comment: If your vector contains all negative numbers, your code will fail.  It will report that the maximum value is 0. Correct that by making the initial value of `max_so_far` equal to the lowest integer.

Comment: @Jim: I got the algorithm from here: http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s08.pdf  So there must be an error in the hard copy too perhaps?

Comment: @Jim: if subvector may include a subvector of length zero, then 0 is indeed the maximum sum when all numbers are negative. So it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to invert the sign of each element in `x` and then run the algorithm:

```
std::vector<int> x;
int max_so_far = 0;
int max_here = 0;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) x[i] = -x[i];

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
{
   max_here = std::max(max_here + x[i], 0);
   max_so_far = std::max(max_so_far, max_here);
}

int min_so_far = -max_so_far;
```

Comment: This will not work. max of negative and zero will always be zero.

Comment: @Neo: yes, because of that I inverted the sign of `x`'s elements.

Comment: @Moron - Exactly. Thats what confused me.

Comment: If all elements are negative, it will return 0. We should start with max_so_far = max_here = -infinity... Of couse, you _could_ consider a subvector of _no_ elements as having sum zero and consider that valid output.

Comment: The maximum sum of a subarray of 0 elements is 0, since you'd sum nothing.

Comment: @MUrilo: If you have an array of 10 elements, and you considered subarrays of _zero_ elements, then the algorithm is valid. Perhaps we are saying the same thing. Anyway...